# Subdivision surface modifier distorting mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I made a mesh, but it is a little jagged, I already used shader smooth but still, I then tried to apply the subdivision surface modifier but it heavily distorts my object. Is there any way to fix this, or any alternatives to my issue?
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need supporting edge loops- https://www.blendersecrets.org/secrets/adding-support-loops-around-edge-loops - but honestly you'll get better results skipping the subdiv and using a Bevel modifier instead

Comment: Ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Toss on a bevel modifier, set it to Angle rather than Vertex weight and set the angle to 60 degrees. Then your subsurf modifier to go under the bevel modifier.